# Wpf partial image display

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I need some tips for a little project.
i am NOT trying to make a game of some sort, but i probably need some game-making techniques.

I have to make a minimap viewer in wpf.

I have a set of map jpg files, but i only have to show a portion of them in a smaller rectangle that i draw on the app window.

The goal is to make a minimap like in most games where you can only see a set portion of the whole map.

I am fairly new in the C# wpf environment so please be specific and if you give some code please explain what is not obvious.

Thank you all.

Comment: Honestly I'm just starting up and haven't tried anything worth mentioning. I have experience in shell based C and now I've been tasked with this app for wondows using graphids so I'm really just reading material for now

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you. I have refered to it. In fact my question is pretty straight forward: i have a large jpg image. But i want only a portion of it to be shown in a specified rectangle (say a canvas).

Comment: Can I understand the 'set of map jpg files' as tiles from which you can compose the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `Image` you can crop it like this:

```
public static Bitmap CropImage(Image source, int x,int y,int width,int height)
{
    Rectangle crop = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

    var bmp = new Bitmap(crop.Width, crop.Height);
    using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        gr.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), crop, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: That's not very suitable approach in WPF.

Comment: @Liero: i have a set of jpg's i.e. I have an 3x3 matrix of jpg's. All these pictures form my global image. My aim is to show the global picture only in a smaller rectangle while keeping the rest of it hidden. I am obviously searching and trying things in the mean tima. I am sorry if it seems that I am "outsourcing" my project.